# Comparing string to background color

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, store

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    if(/*insert if condition here*/)
    {
        cntr = 1;
        void1();
    }
}
```

I'm currently developing a C# Windows store app.
I have a TextBlock that can have a text of either Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo or Violet. I also have seven buttons with different background colors. Now, I want to check if the text of my TextBlock matches the backgound color of the Button clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **BrushConverter** instance to convert the text of the text block into a **Brush** object, then compare that brush against the button's background.

Some example XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="Red" />
    <Button Content="Blue" Background="Blue" Click="OnColorButtonClick" />
    <Button Content="Red" Background="Red" Click="OnColorButtonClick" />
    <Button Content="Green" Background="Green" Click="OnColorButtonClick" />
    <Button Content="Yellow" Background="Yellow" Click="OnColorButtonClick" />
</StackPanel>
```

...and the button handler code (note that all of the buttons in the example use the same click handler):

```
private void OnColorButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var converter = new BrushConverter();
    var textblockBrush =
        converter.ConvertFromString(MyTextBlock.Text) as Brush;
    var button = (Button) sender;
    if (button.Background == textblockBrush)
    {
        // text of my TextBlock matches the backgound color of the Button clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try btn.BackColor.ToString() == textblock.Text to do the comparison

Comment: **BackColor** is a property of a button in Windows Forms, but the OP was asking about WPF.

Answer (score 0):

So I made a quick program to see if this would work and it did. Just follow the notes for what to change. Just do one thing as you are looking over this code. Try and understand what every line is doing.

```
    private void btn2Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//This button color is Control
    {
        if (label1.BackColor == button2.BackColor)//You are going to want to substatut your label name for label1
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here");//This was just to make sure the program did match the colors
        }
    }

    private void btn1Yellow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//This button color is Yellow
    {
        if (label1.BackColor == button1.BackColor)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you changing the color of the button's background?

Comment: So I have been working out this for quite some time now. I can't seem to find the solution. I can tell you a path to follow though. You will first need to find out what color your text is. So Black is #FF000000. Then your will need to test that to the background color of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WPF you need to utilize following properties,

- For TextBlock : `TextBlock.Foreground`  ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.foreground(v=vs.110).aspx))
- For Button event : `Control.Background` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(v=vs.110).aspx))

I'm not going to write the logic since it's but uncleanly what you really want but what you need to do is get the current foreground color applied in `TextBLock` and compare it with the clicking button's `Background` using above properties.

ex : Code for an `IF` comparison

```
 if(TextBlock.Foreground == btn.Background){
      // Color matching
      // Do things here
  }
```

Comment: The **TextBlock** class does not have a static property called "TextBlock".

Comment: @Steven Rands A typo :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    if(button.Background == textBlock.TextBlock)
    {
        cntr = 1;
        void1();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: I'm assuming `textBlock` as used here is supposed to reference a **TextBlock** object instance. The **TextBlock** class does not have a property called "TextBlock", so this code wouldn't compile. Even if you meant the "Text" property that wouldn't work either as you would be trying to compare a **Brush** object to a **string** object.

Comment: Sorry, typing error.
The correct is:

`code` if(button.Background == textBlock.foreground)